# How do I get individual Json data from a facebook graph call?

Tags: php, facebook

Im trying to get shares count from this Facebook graph call using php but am having no luck:

http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://google.com

Try 1

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://google.com");
$parsedJson = json_decode($content, true);
echo $parsedJson['shares'];
```

Try 2

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://google.com");
$parsedJson = json_decode($content, true);
echo $parsedJson->shares;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
echo $parsedJson["http://google.com"]['shares'];
```

Comment: This is incorrect because "http://google.com" is not an array element, but a `stdObject`.

Comment: That would have been true if `json_decode` wasn't called with `true` as the second parameter.

Comment: Aaah, I didn't notice that.  Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

This will work!

```
echo ($parsedJson->{'http://google.com'}->shares);
```